# Best Practice - If match return result

Tags: powershell

**Use Case**

The below script is to be placed in a scheduled task to notify me if my public IP Address changes

The IF match condition is not the correct behaviour

What would be the best way to match if the IP Address changed and output that to host?

**Code**

```
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | select -ExpandProperty ip
$date = (get-date).date
$value = "{0} - {1}" -f ($date),($ip)
Add-Content -Value $value -Path "C:\users\Sumeet\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ip.txt"
$file = Get-Content -Path "C:\users\Sumeet\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ip.txt"

if ($file | Select-String -Pattern $ip) {
clear-host
write-host "Match found at $_ your public IP interface has changed"
}
```

**File Output**

```
Date - IP

9/06/2018 12:00:00 AM - 121.211.177.20

9/06/2018 12:00:00 AM - 121.211.177.20
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What do you expect? You write the actual IP to a file, read the file back and check if the ip is in the file - of course it is - you just wrote it there!

Comment: You should only write to the file if the IP is new or is altered since the last(newest) entry.

Answer (score 1):

I think something similar would be more helpful, as @LotPings suggested. You should update the file only if there is a change and follow up with notification as needed.

Also note, that change of IP can occur at anytime, but your scheduled task will let you know only whenever it is scheduled to run.

```
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | select -ExpandProperty ip
$date = (get-date).date
$value = "{0} - {1}" -f ($date),($ip)

$file = Get-Content -Path "E:\Code\powershell\myPS\2018\Jun\checkPublicIP\ip.txt"

if ($file | Select-String -Pattern $ip) {
    Write-Host "IP is not changed"
}
else {
    #Adding current IP to the file
    Add-Content -Value $value -Path "E:\Code\powershell\myPS\2018\Jun\checkPublicIP\ip.txt"

    #Add more code as needed for notification / email / alert. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling of data is IMO done easier when using csv files as columns/properties are assigned on import.

Because of my locale which doesn't support the date separator `/` or `tt` for AM/PM I had to use a CultureInfo object.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\09\SO_50771712.ps1
$File = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ip.csv"
$CIUS = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

$Actual = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Date = (get-date).ToString("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",$CIUS)
    IP   = (Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json).ip
}
if (!(Test-Path $File)){'"Date","IP"'|Set-Content $File}

$Last=Import-Csv $File|Sort-Object {[DateTime]$_.Date}|Select-Object -Last 1

If ($Last.ip -ne $Actual.ip){
    Write-Host ("Last ip : {0} from: {1}" -f $LAst.IP,$Last.date)
    Write-Host ("New  ip : {0} from: {1}" -f $Actual.IP,$Actual.date)
    Export-Csv $File -InputObject $Actual -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\09\SO_50771712.ps1
Last ip : 92.123.13.83 from: 9/6/2018 09:19:21 PM
New  ip : 92.123.13.84 from: 9/6/2018 09:34:59 PM

> gc $file
"Date","IP"
"9/6/2018 08:51:00 PM","92.123.13.82"
"9/6/2018 09:19:21 PM","92.123.13.83"
"9/6/2018 09:34:59 PM","92.123.13.84"
```